# Weird Quirk - Right Click, then key press not running command in Win7 / IE8

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, windows-registry

I just got a new work computer and am being driven nuts by this odd quirk.

When I'm in Internet Explorer, I'm used to right-clicking on a link using my mouse's touchpad (to bring up the right-click context menu with one option being `Open in New Window`) and then hitting the "N" key and it would open the link in a new window.

However, what's happening for me now is that I right-click and the menu appears and then I press the "N" key and it HIGHLIGHTS the menu command, but I have to press `Enter` to make it execute - I know it's a small thing, but I'd really prefer not having to go through the 2-step process.

However, if I right-click and type "O" for `Open`, it runs that command (actually runs it, rather than highlighting the entry in the context menu) just fine.

Any ideas about how I can change this functionality - Maybe it's a synaptics touchpad issue, maybe an internet explorer issue, maybe I just need to change something in the registry??

My system is Woindows 7 x64 running IE8.

Thanks!!!

Comment: If you hit 'N' multiple times does it highlight some other menu item?

Comment: It does! Darn it!!! - "Send to OneNote" - I gotta get that option off!!!!

Comment: @Karan, It did work!!! - I actually removed it from the registry, but it worked like a charm!!! - THANK YOU!!! Please do add it as an answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments above, the problem was caused by the **Send to OneNote** context menu option which also used the letter 'N' as the shortcut key. To remove it:

1. In IE go to `Tools / Manage Add-ons / Toolbars and Extensions` and disable the **Send to OneNote** BHO (Browser Helper Object) if it's listed.
2. If the above doesn't work, open the registry editor (`Start / Run / regedit`), navigate to the `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MenuExt\Send to OneNote` key and delete it.

   [image: 1]
   (Random image found on some site so wrong item is highlighted, but you get the idea. :)

Comment: AWESOME @Karan!! - Thank you again!!!

Comment: You're most welcome! :)